# How can I add a new page in Magento

Tags: zend-framework, magento

Salaam and hi,

I want to add, a simple page in magento. I am submitting a form and want to submit form on that page and want to use data on that. I don't know Magento and zend but Kohana and CI that are also MVC. So for this purpose should I make both controller and View file and also that XML file that is in layout? And what will be its layout? I don't know much about Magento but actually just want to integrate a small thing in it, for this I will also require a view to show some data there and also some additional CSS and JQuery files so I think for that I will need to use XML. So are these 3 places where I will be doing some thing or some where else? And I don't understand the URL structure of it so if some one can provide some useful resource for that then it will be helpful.

Or please tell if there is some other easy way without going in MVC and I also want a link on that page to come back.

Please tell whatever you know and it will be really appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build a extension that adds your form, listens for data and processes the data and saves it to databalse. As your question is abstract then there is no good answer for that other than redirecting you to learn the basics of magento from:

- http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base
- http://www.magentocommerce.com/services/training (free basics courses)
- [Custom forms in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066127/custom-forms-in-magento)

or search google and magento forums by your keyword "custom forms magento" that will reveal lot of extensions or solutions that others have made available.